# Python: Using threads for processing jobs

Tags: python, multithreading, gil

There is a pretty big multithreaded python2 web-application. In main thread works business logic, in sub-threads mostly database operations running. No TreadPoolExecutor is used now, and it cannot be implemented in the nearest future. I want to add another thread which is supposed to process certain amount of data (fast) and store the result into the DataBase (io-operation). This operation won't be executed very often.

So, the question is: should I run mostly sleeping thread and wait for an event to process data or maybe it's better to spawn new thread from the main when there is enough data and close it when processing were completed? Note, that there are already pretty large amount of threads running for GIL to switch between them.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure threads are the right solution here ?

Comment: Well, actually i'm SURE that subprocesses will do much better :) Though cause of DB operations in threads, there is a performance profit. For now we just cannot get rid of threads cause application is very big and old and mostly has a poor design. Also i'm just wondering. ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you run this process, say, once a day, then the overhead to create the thread and to destroy it is negligible.

A thread that is waiting for a signal (like a message in a queue) doesn't need the CPU, so it doesn't cost you to keep it hanging around.

That means you can look at the other design factors: Error handing, stability, code complexity.

If you have the error handling nailed down, keeping the thread alive is probably better, since that will handle a corner case for you: Accidentally running two instances at the same time.

If the thread can stall or you have problems with deadlocks and things like that, then it's better to kill any existing worker thread and start a clean one.

Comment: I'm aware of the factor that GIL constantly switching between various threads (say after 100 bytecodes processed), even if those threads are sleeping. This can decrease overall performance cause the application already has large amount of threads.

Comment: @sunrize531: Do you have references?

Comment: Also, have you considered to run the task in a new (forked) process?